# Is there a way to create my own "push pins" for a image without using Google Maps API?

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-maps

I am interested in working with friends via the internet on a fantasy world map.  One of the things I want to do is host an image of the map online and allow us to insert push pins into the image that would then be associated with infoboxes.

I don't want to resort to using the Google Map APIs mainly because this is something I want to just share among friends and not publicly.  Terms of usage for the APIs state we would need to make the implementation available for everyone.

This seems simple enough yet I've no idea how to do this.  I looked into image maps, but that requires constant updates to the html markup itself.  I just want to insert/delete/edit pushpins and infoboxes on the image and through our site itself.

Can someone help me get started?

Comment: It is more complex than you think. Remember you have to store the pushpin location and text on the server if you want to share them, otherwise the pushins will disapear on reload/view in anther browser. An AJAX call that updates a database when you create the pushpin should do the trick. Then you would need to make sure to read from the db on load of the image to see stored markers.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out openLayers. http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to resort to using the Google Map APIs mainly because this is something I want to just share among friends and not publicly. Terms of usage for the APIs state we would need to make the implementation available for everyone.

Available, but that doesn't mean you have to e-mail every Internet user in the world to announce the site. You can't password protect the page that's using the Google Maps API, but you can name it http://example.com/you-will-never-guess-this-url.html and just send the link to your friends.

Answer (score 0):

This is only partially what you are after, but may help.

Check out [SpryMap](http://candrews.net/blog/2010/10/introducing-sprymap/). It will provide you with the "scrolling map" effect.  Unfortunately, it doesn't provide anything to do with pushpins. However, if you are decent with CSS & JavaScript, it shouldn't be too difficult to implement.